# Export svg from Inkscape to Corel Draw

Tags: svg, file-conversion, inkscape, coreldraw

I'm working in Inkscape exclusively but sometime people require files writen in cdr file. Is there a way to safely export from Inkscape and then import in Corel Draw? I've used Corel X3 and when I imported svg, I've get garbage (sometime it work, but most of the time I need to recreate the work in Corel Draw). Is there safe format that will work for both applications?

Don't know if SO is right for this type of questions, I've seen similar one that was not closed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found a way, Corel Draw can easily import pdf file. So in inscape you save svg as pdf, then open corel draw and import pdf. Fonts need to be copy to windows machine, but I've tested drawing where I convert all text into curves.

Comment: Sometimes it plots error that PDF file is corrupt, though it is not corrupt (CorelDraw v.12)

Answer (score 0):

Save your file in pdf format in inkscape and select "Convert Text To Path" and then in Corel Draw while opening the pdf file "Import Text as Text". Actually what works here is Converting text to path in Inkscape and Import Text as Text is just, well nothing since no text is there in the pdf but only paths. This helps avoid sitautions where your imported files have weird text formatting and unwanted anomalies.

Comment: this make no sens, if you convert text to path there is nothing to convert to text in Corel Draw. Also my answer say that I convert text to curves so there is no problems with fonts.

Comment: There actually IS: If you keep your curves, the text transformations may get lost... I had a problem with dominant-baseline="middle" been ignored, loading SVG as PDF to CorelDraw v.12